# I think evolution has goal

Tags: evolution

Richard Dawkins says evolution doesn't have any goal. But I think evolution has one. At the end evolution creates intelligent being. If we find another earth like planet evolution sould have the same pattern. Evolution is not a chaotic event. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is not much of a questions, but only an empty proposition which is not supported by any logical arguments or empirical proofs.

Comment: What do you mean at the end? What makes you think we are at the "end" of evolution? If anything can be said to be the "most evolved", that would be viruses, not humans.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you are wrong I am afraid. Evolution is the process of change through time of species by inherited changes. Heritable differences mainly come about from random mutation in the genome. These genetic differences between individuals lead to fitness differences between individuals, ie one individual is better able to produce offspring, thus spreading more of its genes in to the following generation, than another individual. For example, environmental change causes selection for a dark body morph in moths, stabding genetic variation and new mutations affecting body colour is then more favored by selection, and those with the dark body genes survive and reproduce better.

There is no end or goal to evolution. It is often mistakenly said that humans have stopped evolving. This is wrong and to suggest we have is to suggest that evolution is directed and has an ultimate goal. As long as genetic fitness variation exists there will always be some level of evolution because there is a difference between individuals in selection coefficient. Selection is also very unstable, it can change drastically an rapidly, evolution could only then stop if selection was constant and favored one "ultimate genotype" over all others in which case all genetic variation would cease to exist.

If we found another planet which had the exact same conditions and time as earth we may find the same species, but it is not likely. It requires the same mutations and selection processes occurring. Analogous to this is the observation of "many solutions to one problem" where different species use different adaptations to deal with a common problem. For example, geting oxygen is difficult for water deelling species. Sea mammals like whales gather oxygen by going to the surface and breathing and then holding their breath. Fish have evolved gills, a different solution to the same problem, to harvest oxygen from the water. These solutions evolve from random changes with selection acting only on the results (those that could filter oxygen from the water or hold their breath the best survived and reproduce best).

Comment: I'm writing this on my iPhone in an airport - if people have some references for examples and reading please feel free to add them.

Comment: What do you think what is the next evolutionary step for mankind?
I didn't said we would find same species in another planet. I said we may find same pattern. I think evolution has a pattern and there for it can be said as a goal. You put the initial value you will find the final value. I think it is not a chaotic process.

Comment: Just remember that every species is undergoing evolution and few, if any, have evolved intelligence...

Comment: @KarziArafatAhmed Just as evolution can lead to different solutions to one problem, as above, it can also lead to similar ones between species. This is called convergent evolution, given the same selection as on our planet, another planet could host similar species as ours. It is not moving towards a goal. How would it know where to go? What is controlling it?

Comment: @KaziarafatAhmed On the inherently tricky and mostly unanswerable topic of future human evolution you can look at these earlier posts: [Scientifically based theories of future human evolution?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9739/are-there-any-scientifically-based-predictions-or-theories-of-future-human-evolu/9764#9764), [Is evolution possible in contemporary humans?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/how-is-evolution-possible-in-contemporary-humans), ...

Comment: [cnd]: ...also [Medical progress and human evolution?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/has-medical-progress-stopped-human-evolution) @KaziarafatAhmed