# Can human change its morphology or anatomy due to ecological changes?

Tags: evolution, human-anatomy, ecology, adaptation

According to Charles Darwin, as the surrounding environment changes, so changes the anatomy or morphology of a specific organism.

But nowadays, humans have become very advanced in the technology and when the surrounding temperature changes, humans in turn change the surrounding temperature (e.g. the use of ACs), and maintain the surrounding as they like.

What I want to emphasize is can human being evolve with these scopes in mind?

Comment: related question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/has-medical-progress-stopped-human-evolution Incidentally, Darwin was not awarded a knighthood.

Comment: I went ahead and changed it, as other people are going to come in trying to correct it as well.

Comment: i think we have bigger bellies now :P

Comment: It's important to note that [populations evolve; individual organisms do not](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/misconceptions_faq.php#a4).

Comment: @p.s.w.g very good concept to be focused so can the population evolve now

Comment: @agharehanabbas Yes, [human populates can and do evolve now](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/misconceptions_faq.php#a8)

Comment: @ p.s.w.g That's Berkeley opinion. Which is wrong :)